# c cast and deference a pointer strict aliasing

Tags: c11, strict-aliasing

In http://blog.regehr.org/archives/1307, the author claims that the following snippet has undefined behavior:

```
unsigned long bogus_conversion(double d) {
  unsigned long *lp = (unsigned long *)&d;
  return *lp;
}
```

The argument is based on http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7, which specified the allowed access circumstances. However, in the footnote(88) for this bullet point, it says this list is only for checking aliasing purpose, so I think this snippet is fine, assuming `sizeof(long) == sizeof(double)`.

My question is whether the above snippet is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet is erroneous but not because of aliasing. First there is a simple rule that says to deference a pointer to object with a different type than its effective type is wrong. Here the effective type is `double`, so there is an error.
This safeguard is there in the standard, because the bit representation of a `double` must not be a valid representation for `unsigned long`, although this would be quite exotic nowadays.

Second, from a more practical point of view, `double` and `unsigned long` may have different alignment properties, and accessing this in that way may produce a bus error or just have a run time penalty.

Generally casting pointers like that is almost always wrong, has no defined behavior, is bad style and in addition is mostly useless, anyhow. Focusing on *aliasing* in the argumentation about these problems is a bad habit that probably originates in incomprehensible and scary gcc warnings.

If you really want to know the bit representation of some type, there are some exceptions of the "effective type" rule. There are two portable solutions that are well defined by the C standard:

- Use `unsigned char*` and inspect the bytes.
- Use a `union` that comprises both types, store the value in there and read it with the other type. By that you are telling the compiler that you want an object that can be seen as both types. But here you should not use `unsigned long` as a target type but `uint64_t`, since you have to be sure that the size is exactly what you think it is, and that there are no trap representations.

To illustrate that, here is the same function as in the question but with defined behavior.

```
unsigned long valid_conversion(double d) {
  union {
    unsigned long ul;
    double d;
  } ub = { .d = d, };
  return ub.ul;
}
```

My compiler (gcc on a Debian, nothing fancy) compiles this to *exactly* the same assembler as the code in the question. Only that you know that this code is portable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The second point could be avoided if I chose two types that have the same alignment, e.g. `float`. The first point is more interesting to me. Search "effective type" in C11 leads me to 6.5p7 (the link I posted in the question); if this is what you had in mind for point 1, the footnote 88 says the list is intended to check aliasing, not disallowed access.

Comment: @AlbertNetymk, the point is that footnotes are not normative, the text itself is. So maybe that was the "only" initial intention, but the imposed rules are stronger. Compiler can do surprising things, and you just don't know in which context your code could be evaluated, inlining, link-time optimization, whatever. The standard is there to give clear rules of what you can do, the rest is undefined. And undefined just means that on your platform you may be fine, if your documentation says so. In general you aren't.

Comment: @AlbertNetymk, also I really can't follow the fascination with all of this. Code that uses such things is just very bad quality. There is no excuse for using such constructs.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Code that uses such constructs can sometimes outperform code that doesn't by a factor of two or better--sometimes even by an order of magnitude.  What I find puzzling is the belief by compiler writers that the authors if the Standard intended that constructs which were well-defined in C dialects for many platforms should cease to be usable on those same platforms even when no better equivalents exist.

Comment: @supercat, I just don't buy it, at least not any more. For the case that was presented here. Creating a `union` assigning to one member and read from the other (with the precaution of having the correct types) will be portable and will be optimized on most platforms to exactly the same assembler as the pointer cruft. And then, performance critical code that needs such reinterpretation of data, has serious problems.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Given `struct s1 { uint16_t h1; uint8_t h2,x[3]; }; struct s2 { uint16_t h1; uint8_t h2,x[5]; uint64_t long ll1; };`, how is one supposed to write a function that can accept a pointer of either type and read members `h1` and `h2` thereof?  If `uint64_t` requires 64-bit alignment, casting pointers to 75% of the members of a `struct s1[]` to `union s1s2*` will invoke Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @JensGustedt: For the specific case given in the question, a union is probably the way to go, but there are many cases where the "union" approach isn't workable in Standard C.  If there were a rule that said that an address with any alignment may be converted to a union pointer if the union has *any* member compatible with that alignment, and any field of the union thus identified whose type could accept that alignment could be used to reinterpret data of any other type in the union or of character type, then the union approach might be workable.  No such rule exists, however.

Comment: @supercat, you seem to be trapped in "pointer thinking". You can defiine a `union` of the two structure and initialize them with a value of either type there is no difference. Don't cast pointers, casts are evil. Tell the compiler that you want an object that can be interpreted as both types. If he can, he will help you and optimize things very well. If there really is an alignment problem (or whatever) he will take care of it. Don't bother with it yourself. And if, as said, performance critical code depends on it, you have a design problem.

Comment: @JensGustedt: What you call "pointer thinking" is what C was designed for.  If you only want to do things that can be done in FORTRAN, you could write code in FORTRAN-95 and it would likely run better than in C.  If one needs a few some big objects and a lot of little objects, and wants a function that can work with both interchangeably, using a union type for every instance of the little objects would defeat the whole purpose of having both big and little objects.  For some purposes that may be fine, but for many others it would make the language totally useless.